# 64-bit hash/digest in C

Tags: c, encryption, hash, openssl

I am trying to find out if there is any API in C for calculating a 64 bit hash.
I found out that some people use top 64 bits of MD5/SHA1 etc. Is it a good approach?

Comment: A truncated SHA1 is better than any true 64-bit hash due to its larger internal state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [SipHash](http://131002.net/siphash/siphash.pdf) in its form as a MAC (which requires key management, though). It is particularly well-suited for short input messages and aims at cryptographic strength. A C [implementation](https://github.com/emboss/siphash-c) is also available.

But if you really care about someone actively messing around with your files, you shouldn't restrict yourself to 64 bits of security. 64 bits can be broken even by brute force today, given enough time and resources. You should use SHA-256 or stronger for that. Or let me state it the other way round, blacklisting broken options: don't use MD5 (or MD-anything for that matter). Use SHA-1 only if you can't use SHA-256 for some reason.

Using a hash also has the advantage that you don't need to manage any keys (opposed to using a MAC). You should just keep the hashes you compute in a different place than the files you are about to monitor - otherwise somebody tampering with your files can easily tamper with the checksum, too.

#### Regarding whether truncating hashes is good or bad

In theory, I can't see why it should be wrong to truncate a let's say 160 bit hash value down to 64 bit, regardless of whether you take the most significant bits or the least significant bits or pick them using any arbitrary pattern. The only reason why this isn't done more often that I can think of is efficiency - why bring the big guns if there are more efficient algorithms for handling the smaller problems.

In what follows, I assume a cryptographically secure hash for this purpose, general-purpose hashes are quite a different topic - they might expose attack surfaces when truncated for all I know.

But, for a cryptographically secure hash, unless the algorithm is broken, we can assume that its output is indistinguishable from that of a uniformly distributed random variable.

If we truncate this value now, we don't offer any further insight into the inner workings of the algorithm. Still, we *do* weaken the security by the simple fact that brute-forcing (be it collisions or finding pre-images) now takes less time by laws of probability.

For example, finding a collision for a 64 bit hash takes roughly 2^32 attempts on average  - says the Birthday Paradoxon. If you truncate your output down to the least significant 32 bits of the original 64 bit hash, then you will find collisions in time roughly 2^16, because you simply ignore the most significant 32 bits and the de-facto uniform distribution does the rest - it's like you started searching for collisions with a 32 bit value in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea. **Hash function values are always meant to be taken *as a whole*.**

For the implied question of "how to calculate a 64 bit hash": what's your intended use? Remember that 64 bits are too few for a crypto-strength hash function.

Comment: Even I thought so. Can you suggest some method for 64 bit hash.

Comment: @ManikSidana: What's it going to be used for? This page might be interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions

Answer (score 1):

Use CRC to protect against random changes.

Use HMAC to protect against an attacker changing your files. HMAC uses a secret key that is necessary to generate and verify the tags. The result of an HMAC is as long as the underlying hash function (e.g. 20 bytes for an HMAC-SHA1), but it is frequently truncated. I.e. according to NIST SP 800-107 p.14 64-96 bits should be enough for most applications.

Comment: CRC won't suffice for me. I want to protect my file from tampering.

Comment: It would help if you could add this clarification to your question. It is also not clear what you do with the hash. E.g. if you append the hash to your file then an attacker can modify file and hash and hence any un-keyd hash no matter what size is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

64 bits is small for a hash and usually, hashes are meant to be taken as a whole.

Now, what do you need these 64 bits for ? Answer will depend of expected usage.

Keep in mind that md5 is quite broken nowadays and 64 bits is very low security.

Comment: I have a file having not more than 256 characters. I want to create a 64 bit hash. The idea is that this code should be able to tell whether the file contents have been altered or not.

Comment: Then in this case, good old CRC32 + checksum is a good candidate (or more modern, crc64). You don't need cryptographic strength, just basic data check.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need integrity checking against random changes, then a simple checksum as given in the other answers *may* be enough.

If you need cryptographic strength to ensure the original content, then 64 bit is too weak. Better use the full value of an unbroken algorithm, i.e. not MD5. SHA1 is still okay, but for longer term security better use SHA256. Or even go further with HMAC, as mentioned in the other answer.

There is nothing wrong with using the truncated value of a cryptographic hash. In fact, SHA224/384 are calculated by calculating a SHA256/512 hash with a different initialization vector and then truncating the result. However, this is only valid for *cryptographic* hashes. It may be a bad idea for normal checksums and table hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenSSL's API for the calculations.(www.openssl.org).